# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 33: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: pandas, unicode

I have this column in a pandas DataFrame which contains addresses values, a total mess. They all differ in notation, length, numeric format, etc. Here is one example on how different values can be in this column:

['Carrera 71 no 15-14', 'Diagonal 79 a no 76-290', 'Calle20eno73-71', 'Calle 71 no 60 b 06 villas del sol', 'Carrera 49 bno26-b50', 'Calle 70 sur #35a-51', 'Calle 42 no 63c133 apto  202 conquistadore', 'San pedro de los milagros']

My first approach to start the cleaning process was trying to use str split to grab the first word, and from there start to define some kind of standard, like this:

```
df["Direccion"].str.split(" ", n = 0, expand = True)
```

and

```
df['Direccion'] = df['Direccion'].astype('|S')
```

But when I tried to do so, I got this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 33: ordinal not in range(128)

I have no idea what to do to fix it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Since your code doesn't contain `encode` can I presume you're still using Python 2?

Comment: `U+FFFD` is *replacement character*, so it means that in previous decoding you had invalid data (which may hint on a previous bug). Maybe you want to use `|U` instead of `|S` (for unicode strings). Personally I would write a python function (and call it with `df["Direccion"].map(my_cleaning_function)`): you have much more control (Python is a scripting language, so good string handling, so use pure Python and not pandas/numpy for this complex process)

Comment: Thank you! I will try it.